# Removing multiple characters (forming a word) from a string

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x

I have a challenge which I have tried to solve using `split.strings` but that seems to not be designed for immutable strings the way I need but mainly for whitespace and single character removal. I have also tried regex but as they are not due in my current python course for a few weeks I am a bit stuck on how they work (although I know the basics of what they are for).

So, I have a JSON file that presents machine and people data from a factory and I need to parse the machine data separate from the people data that is gathered within the facility. Converting the JSON file and selecting the required data is working but within one of the parameters called `name` is a mix of people and machine info I need to separate out. An example of two branches is below:

```
"id": "b4994c877c9c",
    "name": "forklift_0001", # here is the machine
    "areaId": "Tracking001",
    "areaName": "Ajoneuvo",
    "color": "#FF0000",
    "coordinateSystemId": "CoordSys001",
    "coordinateSystemName": null,
    "covarianceMatrix": [

"id": "b4994c879275",
    "name": "guest_0001", # here is a person
    "areaId": "Tracking001_2D",
    "areaName": "staff1",
    "color": "#CCFF66",
    "coordinateSystemId": "CoordSys001",
    "coordinateSystemName": null,
    "covarianceMatrix": [
```

The code I have to convert is below:

```
for f in file_list:
    print('Input file: ' + f) # Replace with desired operations

with open(f, 'r') as f:

    distros = json.load(f)
    output_file = 'Output' + str(output_nr) + '.csv'

    with open(output_file, 'w') as text_file:
        for distro in distros:
            print(distro['name'] + ',' + str(distro['positionTS']) + ',' + str(distro['position']), file=text_file)
```

So what I need to do within the `distro['name']` array (is it an array??) is to go through the 500k lines and ask it to remove anything that isn't forklift, crane, machine, etc, leaving only them (and later the opposite) and this I cannot figure out.

All help sincerely appreciated.

Comment: What you can do is you can list the words you want to delete and just use `if distro['name'] in list_of_strings_to_delete: #do something with this name, clear it to be empty string or change to default, etc.`

Comment: So your issue is only with the `"name"` key and you need to tell whether the data represents a person or equipment? If so, do you have a complete list of what words would represent each?

Comment: Are you trying to just take the json file and split it into 2 json files, one with machines and one with people?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand your question you want to give each entry a flag 'machine' or 'person', based on the "name" tag.

Assigning such a flag (or just directly writing to the appropriate file) could be done with for instance something like

```
with open(file1, 'w') as _file1, open(file2, 'w') as _file2, open(file3, 'w') as _file3:
    for distro in distros:
        yourstring = distro['name'] + ',' + str(distro['positionTS']) + ',' + str(distro['position'])

        if distro['name'].startswith(('forklift','crane',...)):
            _file1.write(yourstring)
        elif distro['name'].startswith(('guest','employee',...)):
            _file2.write(yourstring)
        else:
            _file3.write(yourstring)
```

The three files that have been opened for writing together will contain all the entries in the end, split up between machines, people, and neither of both.

Does that solve your issue?

Comment: Basically that solved the issue.  I needed to construct a slightly different if function (the elif and else parts were unneeded) and then I had to remind myself to set the code blocks and it worked.  I appreciate you telling me an if function would work, my thinking had become really uptight...

Comment: Glad that worked. Please, also see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)